# Basic Django staticfile deployment on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

[image]

I'm trying to deploy a django project to heroku (previously on openshift), but cannot get the static files right. The project structure is above. In firebug I'm getting:

```
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://myproject.herokuapp.com/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
bootstrap.min.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://myproject.herokuapp.com/static/css/landing-page.css"
landing-page.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://myproject.herokuapp.com/static/js/jquery.js"
jquery.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://myproject.herokuapp.com/static/js/jquery-validate.js"
jquery-...date.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://myproject.herokuapp.com/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"
bootstrap.min.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://myproject.herokuapp.com/static/js/val.js"
val.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - https://myproject.herokuapp.com/static/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
```

The abridged settings.py file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


....


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app1',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

....


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/js'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/css')
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
```

mysite/wsgi.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Comment: I did read and try that out earlier without success, this is the current iteration

Comment: Well, that page shows you what to put in your wsgi file. You haven't posted that file.

Comment: mysite/wsgi.py added now.

Comment: yea read this https://realpython.com/blog/python/migrating-your-django-project-to-heroku/#amazon-s3, you need to prepare you application for Heroku deployment, you don't need to use amazon for static I'm just pin pointing you how can you prepare rest of the app for Heroku, as for `static` files, @DanielRoseman shared what's you need for them

Comment: I'm not using whitenoise. I assumed that was optional. Is that incorrect?

Comment: What makes you think it is optional? If you want to serve assets on Heroku, you need it.

Comment: My mistake for `whitenoise` you will need to use it, but here you can use this, read the docs https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template

Comment: I installed whitenoise and pasted in the wsgi code you linked to above Daniel, and its now working! Thank you. I'll read through the links you provided SvekarP  as well. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Changing STATIC_ROOT to BASE_DIR (from PROJECT_ROOT) seemed to help.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```